# Need an sbt tool release in a single install package

Tags: scala, sbt

I have downloaded sbt-0.13.11.tgz and installed it, which seems to be just contain the sbt-launcher.jar jar file (not sbt tool itself). I run the sbt script and it immediately tries to download sbt-0.13.11.jar (the actual tool) from an external repository, and maybe more for other dependencies. I am not able to connect to these repositories via our proxies at my customer site, however I can import files to my customer's networks. Is there a complete sbt package that includes all dependencies?